# Counting Attempts of an event in R

Tags: r

I'm relatively new in R and learning. I have the following data frame = data

```
 ID   grade   Test_Date
  1     56      01-25-2012
  1     63      02-21-2016
  1     73      02-31-2016
  2     41      12-23-2015
  2     76      01-07-2016
  3     66      02-08-2016
```

I am looking to count the number of people (in this case only two unique individuals) who passed their tests after multiple attempts(passing is defined as 65 or over). So the final product would return me a list of unique ID's who had multiple counts until their test scores hit 65. This would inform me that approx. 66% of the clients in this data frame require multiple test sessions before getting a passing grade.

Below is my idea or concept more or less, I've framed it as an if statement
If ID appears twice
count how often it appears, until TEST GRADE >= 65

```
                ifelse(duplicated(data$ID), count(ID), NA)
```

I'm struggling with the second piece where I want to say, count the occurrence of ID until grade >=65.

The other option I see is some sort of loop. Below is my attempt

```
             for (i in data$ID) {
                  duplicated(datad$ID)
                  count(data$ID)
                  Here is where something would say until =65
                  }
```

Again the struggle comes in how to tell R to stop counting when grade hits 65.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread(" ID   grade   Test_Date
  1     56      01-25-2012
                    1     63      02-21-2016
                    1     73      02-31-2016
                    2     41      12-23-2015
                    2     76      01-07-2016
                    3     66      02-08-2016")

# count the number of try per ID then get only the one that have been successful
dt <- dt[, N:=.N, by=ID][grade>=65]

# proportion of successful having tried more than once
length(dt[N>1]$ID)/length(dt$ID)
[1] 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using the `aggregate` function and subsetting that returns the maximum score for testers that took the the test more than once starting from their second test.

```
multiTestMax <- aggregate(grade~ID, data=df[duplicated(df$ID),], FUN=max)
multiTestMax
  ID grade
1  1    73
2  2    76
```

To get the number of rows, you can use `nrow`:

```
nrow(multiTestMax)
2
```

or the proportion of all test takers

```
  nrow(multiTestMax) / unique(df$ID)
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID   grade   Test_Date
1     56      01-25-2012
1     63      02-21-2016
1     73      02-31-2016
2     41      12-23-2015
2     76      01-07-2016
3     66      02-08-2016")
```

Comment: I've tried this way and I get the following error: Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found. Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: What type of object are you working with? A data.frame or a data.table? This method works for the example above. I'll add the data I used to my answer.

Comment: I'm using a data frame. The ID is coded as numerical and grades as numerical as well. I tried changing ID to factor to see I this had an effect but no dice. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Does the above example work for you when you copy and paste it?

Comment: interesting, it works on the data that I placed up here, but when I attempt it on the data set I have in R it isn't working. I'm going to fish around see what might be the issue

Comment: I had another question, How would I keep the test date of that max value? Is there a way to add it into the aggregate function? so that the output of the first subset includes date?

Comment: One method would be to merge the result in my answer to the original data.frame using by=c("ID", "grade").

Comment: Great advice makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option, though the other two work just fine:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 <- dat %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(
        multiattempts = n() > 1 & any(grade < 65),
        maxgrade = max(grade)
    )
dat2
# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#      ID multiattempts maxgrade
#   <int>         <lgl>    <int>
# 1     1          TRUE       73
# 2     2          TRUE       76
# 3     3         FALSE       66
sum(dat2$multiattempts) / nrow(dat2)
# [1] 0.6666667
```